# Надо получить данные из четырех таблиц из базы данных mysql, с помощью php+ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Есть 4 таблицы в базе: person(id, name, lastname), city(id, title), transport(id, title, price, date), hotel(id, title, price). 
Имеется html форма:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
<form method="GET" action="/">
  <select name="personname">
    <option value="Иван">Иван</option>
    <option value="Сергей">Сергей</option>
  </select>
  <input name="citytitle" type="text">
  <input name="hoteltitle" type="text">
  <input name="transportdate1" type="date">
  <input name="transportdate2" type="date">
  <input name="price1" type="number">
  <input name="price2" type="number">
  <button id="submit">Искать</button>
</form>
<div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php?person=' + $('select[name="personname"]').val() + '&citytitle=' + $('input[name="citytitle"]').val() + '&hoteltitle=' + $('input[name="hoteltitle"]').val() + '&transportdate1=' + $('input[name="transportdate1"]').val() + '&transportdate2=' + $('input[name="transportdate2"]').val() + '&price1=' + $('input[name="price1"]').val() + '&price2=' + $('select[name="price2"]').val(),
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
                if (data == ""){
                    $('div.result').html("Поиск дал 0 результатов");
                }else{
                    $('div.result').html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

и содержимое script.php:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php"; // подключаемся к базе данных
foreach("$_GET['personname']"){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `personname` = $_GET['personname']";
    $t = mysql_query($query);
    if (($t) and (mysql_num_rows($t) > 0)) {
        $sql = mysql_fetch_array($t);
        echo "
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="personname">$sql[name]</td>
    <td id="citytitle"> *?* </td>
    <td id="transportdate"> *?* </td>
    <td id="hoteltitle"> *?* </td>
    <td id="pricetransport_pricehotel"> *?* </td>
  </tr>
</table>";
    }
};
?>
```

Вот тут в php надо сделать так: вывести данные из таблиц, соответствующий данным из формы поиска, потом суммировать price из таблицы transport + price из таблицы hotel. И вывести на таблицу

Как можно сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста. *В php коде есть ошибки.
Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: В ajax запросах можно передать `data`, а то url сильно длинный. Что именно не выполняется в php скрипте? У вас даже "уловок" на ошибки нет, как вы о них узнаете....

Comment: Здесь надо делать выборку из нескольких таблиц. Как это можно реализовать? и делать операции?

Comment: Если таблицы связаны, то sql + Join, если нет, просто делайте 4 разных запроса (либо балуйтесь подзапросами) и выводите уже на php как вам нужно.

Comment: таблицы особо не связаны, а как делать 4 разных запроса? можете пример привести?

Comment: так у Вас же есть пример. Только у Вас один запрос: `$query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE personname = $_GET['personname']";
    $t = mysql_query($query);`, а Вы сделайте еще 3, только с разными `$query`. В чем собственно проблема так сделать?